# SQL Server query order by column containing string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I'm filling my ASP.NET dropdownlist from a column (`nvarchar`) in my SQL Server database.

Is there any way that I can bring rows containing a keyword to the beginnning of my returned result set?

For instance I have these records in my table:

```
abc
abc1
abcd2
abcXYZ3
adfdf3XYZ
abcd5
```

I want to have rows containg `XYZ` at the top of my dropdownlist, i.e:

```
abcXYZ3
adfdf3XYZ
abc
abc1
abcd2
abcd5
```

Is it possible to create a SQL query for this purpose, for instance something like this:

```
select * 
from myTable 
order by (mycolumn LIKE '%XYZ%')
```

How can I get my desired result? If it is not possible in SQL Server, how can I do it in my C# code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do it in SQL you could use

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN mycolumn LIKE '%XYZ%' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END,
          mycolumn
```

Answer (score 2):

You could order by the number of occurences:

```
SELECT column,
       len(column) - len(replace(column,@text,'')) AS MatchNumber

FROM   table

ORDER BY len(column) - len(replace(column,@text,''))
```

This has the advantage of ordering by the number of times a match occurs, but is biased towards longer strings with more matches.

Answer (score 1):

Split it out, add the items that contain keywords first and then after add the others.

Answer (score 0):

-- on the Oracle 11g

```
select myField
  from myTable
order by instr(myField, 'XYZ') desc
```